# std::unordered_map how to free struct created with malloc. Are 2 queries into the map required?

Tags: c++, malloc, unordered-map

The following block of code seems to run fine
Generates:

Add 1000 things
_MyMap now holds [1000] things
_MyMap free'd and erased.  size now [0]

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct _entry
{
    int now;
} ENTRY, * PENTRY;

std::unordered_map<int, PENTRY> _MyMap;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, PENTRY>::iterator itEntry;

int Now()
{
    return 10;
}
```

main function, adding comments because the site won't let me just add code

```
int main()
{   
    PENTRY pE = NULL;

    std::pair<itEntry, bool> r;

    printf("Add 1000 things\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        pE = (PENTRY)malloc(sizeof(ENTRY));
        pE->now = Now();

        r = _MyMap.insert(std::make_pair(i, pE));

        if (false == r.second)
        {
            printf("For some crazy reason its already there\n");
            continue;
        }
    }

    // OK, theres probably 1000 things in there now
    printf("_MyMap now holds [%u] things\n", _MyMap.size() );

    // The following seems stupid, but I don't understand how to free the memory otherwise
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        // first query
        auto it = _MyMap.find(i);

        // if malloc failed on an attempt earlier this could be NULL right?
        // I've had free impls crash when given NULL, so I check.
        if (it != _MyMap.end() &&
            NULL != it->second)
            free(it->second);

        // second query
        _MyMap.erase(i);
    }

    printf("_MyMap free'd and erased.  size now [%u]\n", _MyMap.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Questions are inline in the comments

Comment: Why use `malloc` just put the structure into the map?

Comment: What is `itEntry`? What type is `_Map`? Please share a [MCVE]. The answer to your question is not clear from what you've posted.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what the right way is with these snippets.  My personal opinion is to not store pointers in a library container unless someone's stuck a gun against my head and demanded it or I want the code to be buggy as hell. Allow the container to store and manage the object where possible.

Comment: At the very least, use a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw one.

Comment: Checking against `NULL` before calling `free` is redundant.

Comment: @RichardCritten what would that code look like?

r = _Map.insert(std::make_pair(id, {now, then}));
What if one of the vars was a string that was allocated elsewhere?

Comment: Can't you just `_Map.erase(it)`, i.e. erase the iterator you already have?

Comment: `_Map` is a reserved identifier.

Comment: @chup The map has no idea where those pointers you're placing in it come from.  So of course *you* are responsible for deallocating the memory.

Comment: @chup Without an [mcve] for your current question, it's hard to post a solution.

Comment: I will update the code with a simple example. 
In the mean time.  Are 2 queries required?

Comment: @chup -- *Doesn't the following find it again to remove it?* -- What is your definition of "remove"?  To remove the entry from the map, then erase is called.  That has absolutely nothing to do with your outside setup code of calling `malloc`, which you are now responsible for maintaining by issuing a `free` call somewhere in your application.  How you get to those pointers that you've allocated could have been done any number of ways -- you chose to use your map to find them.

Comment: @RichardCritten How does one "just put the struct in the map"?  Thanks

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie remove:  Get it out of the collection and free up any memory it used.  What is the "right" way to do this?

Comment: @chup -- The map is only responsible for maintaining the map data structure, nothing more nothing less.  The `erase` just removes that node from the data structure.  Again, the map knows nothing about where your pointers came from, whether they came from a call to `malloc`, `new`, `_alloca`, or you plain old stuck a non-allocated pointer to a variable in the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
auto it = _Map.find(idUser);    
if (it != _Map.end())
{
    free(it->second);
    _Map.erase (it);
}
```

But it's really not a good idea to store a raw pointer in a collection this way. You should, ideally, just store the data directly in the map rather than storing a pointer to it. Otherwise, use `std::unique_ptr` so that the destruction of the pointer automatically frees the data.

Comment: David, that looks like what I was after.  Can you provide the syntax you're suggesting so I'm clear?  Thanks

Comment: Either `std::unordered_map<int, ENTRY> _MyMap;` or `std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<ENTRY>> _MyMap;`

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I missed that overload